# How to use nested namespace to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have the following operators defined in the corresponding namespaces:

```
namespace literals
{

constexpr ID operator"" _ID(const unsigned long long dyngateID)
{
    // ...
    // return a constructed id
}

namespace multiplied
{

constexpr ID operator"" _ID(const unsigned long long dyngateID)
{
    // ...
    // return an id constructed in a specific way
}

} // namespace multiplied
} // namespace literals
```

In a .cpp file I would like to use both functions, hence I've declared `using namespace literals` and when I am declaring `using namespace multiplied` in a concrete function I am getting `ambiguous call to overloaded function` compile error. How can I differentiate these functions?

```
Test.cpp

using namespace literals;

void f()
{
    // here I am using literals' _ID which is fine
    const Type id{1_ID};
}
void g()
{
    // here I want to use multiplied's _ID, but obviously I am failing to do so
    using namespace multiplied;
    const Type id{1_ID};
}
```

Comment: You need some way to distinguish between the two functions. Right now they are exactly the same (their *signature* is exactly the same). How would the compiler, or even you, decide which one to use in which situation?

Comment: And for possible solutions, perhaps user-defined literals isn't the correct solution here for you "specific" way, perhaps you should consider a *factory function* instead? Especially if it's the exception to the "normal" way of creating `ID` objects.

Comment: I guess you can put the first `_ID` in a nested namespace, too. Then in each function you could import the right namespace and no collisions should occur.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The two functions' implementation are different, hence the second: multiplied's _ID operator multiplies `1` by 10^6. These function are in the local library which I have to use.

Comment: @Al.G. No, I am not allowed to change anything in that library as it is used by many programmers. Also these nested namespaces are implemented intentionally: to give opportunity to either use `1` multiplied by 10^6 or just 1. In my case I need to use both.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If someone needs 1 to be multiplied by 10^6, he/she just includes appropriate namespace, e.g., `using namespace multiplied` and that's it: nested _ID operator will be used automatically. Otherwise, he/she just includes `using namespace literals`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't there a way to use `multiplied` nested namespace directly? For example, `multiplied::1_ID`

Comment: The compiler doesn't look at a functions implementation when it matches functions, only the signature (function name and arguments, basically). If two functions have the same signature, the compiler can't distinguish between them and you have the ambiguous overload errors. The compiler can't know anything about your intentions, only about the actual signature your functions have. Perhaps your implementation isn't using the design as intended? Perhaps the design is flawed? Perhaps the requirements or their analysis are wrong? You need to talk to whomever gave you this assignment to clarify.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I understand that the compiler looks at function's declaration... I just wanted to say that here namespaces are used for differentiating between 2 functions: depending on which namespace you include. OK, maybe my question was too project related/specific.

Comment: I'll just use `1'000'000` instead of using _ID operator and there won't be any need to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: If you want to use namespaces to differentiate between two otherwise equal functions (from the compilers perspective), then you can't be using `using namespace ...` to pull both functions into the same namespace. Either don't do `using namespace literals;` in the global namespace (use it at a narrower scope, like inside a function), or talk to your professor (or whoever gave you the assignment) if your requirements analysis, design and implementation are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name lookup rules for `using namespace` are such that the declarations introduced by it appear to be located in the inner-most namespace scope enclosing both the current namespace scope and the target namespace scope.

Therefore it is no good to disambiguate based on the scoping of multiple reachable `using namespace` statements.

Instead you can import the declaration with a `using` declaration:

```
void g()
{
    using multiplied::operator""_ID;
    const Type id{1_ID};
}
```

This will behave as if the operator was declared in the scope, so that name lookup will stop there and won't look at the declaration imported by the outer `using namespace`.

---

Alternatively, you can call the user-defined literal operator directly with a qualified call:

```
void g()
{
    const Type id{multiplied::operator""_ID(1)};
}
```

---

As another possibility you can always limit the scope of the `using namespace` statements, so that only one of `using namespace literals;` or `using namespace literals::multiplied;` is reachable from any given scope using the operator, e.g.:

```
// no using namespace at this scope

void f()
{
    using namespace literals;
    const Type id{1_ID};
}
void g()
{
    using namespace literals::multiplied;
    const Type id{1_ID};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace one
{
    int func(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;
    }

    namespace two
    {
        int func(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 * num2;
        }
    }
}

int f()
{
    return one::two(1, 2) + 10;
}
int g()
{
    return one::two::func(3, 4) + 10;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << g() << std::endl;
}
```

The above code will compile and run perfectly fine, and will work as expected, with `f()` using `one::func()` and `g()` using `one::two::func()`. If you have to write `using namespace one;' then you can do something like this:

```
using namespace one;

int f()
{
    return func(1, 2) + 10;
}
int g()
{
    return two::func(3, 4) + 10;
}
```

This will also result in the same output.